# Smooth scroll anchor jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create navigation with anchor URL' and smooth scroll.
But on that page I use a sticky header with a height of 88px.

How can I create a smooth scroll, based on class `product-anchor-links-action`?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rx0txmek/2/

My current HTML:

```
<div class="product-page-nav">
    <div class="container">
    <ol class="product-anchor-links-list">
        <li class="product-anchor-links-item"><a href="#productbeschrijving" class="product-anchor-links-action">Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="product-anchor-links-item"><a href="#specificaties" class="product-anchor-links-action">Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="product-anchor-links-item"><a href="#reviews" class="product-anchor-links-action">Nav 3</a></li>
    </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You aware you don't have any element with id `reviews`, right?!.... I really don't get your question because you have all you need in jsFiddle, just looks like you didn't put much effort to understand your code

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for your reply. Yes I was aware of the, but I changed the fiddle, so that is complete. To only thing is that I can not get it right/working. The smooth scroll is not working and can not get it right, that it is based on the class.

Comment: Your jsFiddle works as expected so maybe explain instead what are you expecting? `that it is based on the class` What do you mean?

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks! It currently works, but it does check the a href, instead of the class name `product-anchor-links-action`. So to should only work for elements with that class. So that other <a> class will not influanced.

Comment: `$('.product-anchor-links-action').click(...);`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract the height of the sticky header from the scrollTop value. When there is no sticky, the value will be 0 (you can just use the .height() value if the sticky is always present).

```
$('a').click(function(){

    var stickyHeight = $('.sticky').length ? $('.sticky').height() : 0

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - stickyHeight 
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

If there is no $('.stickyHeader')

Comment: Thanks! That works fine, but it does check the click on a <a> and not based on the class `product-anchor-links-action`. How can I change that?

Comment: The 'a' in the code above is a selector. So just change $('a').click to $('.product-anchor-links-action').click