# jQuery utilizing smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some difficulty getting my webpage to utilize a smooth scroll. I have a navbar at the top of the page with 4 options on it. Each option corresponds to a section further down on the page. I would like to be able to click on those items in the navbar and have a smooth scroll down to its corresponding section. I've tried utilizing both the below questions (among several other online resources!!), but I can't seem to get it work. Any assistance offered would be much appreciated! Summarized version of code is below

[jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element/6677069#6677069)

[Smooth scroll anchor jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128342/smooth-scroll-anchor-jquery)

HTML

```
<ul id="navbar">
            <li><a class="about" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a class="shop" href="#shop">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a class= "featured" href="#featured">FEATURED</a></li>
            <li><a class="updates" href="#updates">UPDATES</a></li>
        </ul>

<div id="handcrafted"></div>
<div id="shop"></div>
<div id="featured"></div>
<div id="updates"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.about').click( function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top
     }, 400);
});


$('.shop').click( function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#shop').offset().top
     }, 400);
});



$('.featured').click( function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#featured').offset().top
     }, 400);
});



$('.updates').click( function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#updates').offset().top
     }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div id="handcrafted"></div>` should be `<div id="about"></div>`

And if you're dealing with `<a>`, I suggest to add `e.preventDefault()` all the time unless you want a pure `<a>`.

```js
$('a').click( function(e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     $('html').animate({
          scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 400);
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navbar">
            <li><a class="about" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a class="shop" href="#shop">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a class= "featured" href="#featured">FEATURED</a></li>
            <li><a class="updates" href="#updates">UPDATES</a></li>
        </ul>

<div id="about">ABOUT</div>
<div id="shop">SHOP</div>
<div id="featured">FEATURED</div>
<div id="updates">UPDATES</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Has worked perfectly